# Transmit data from form to datatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using the ajax-datatables-rails gem to use the datatables jquery plugin with server-side processing.

I have the table and a form below to filter the table with data that is not displayed in it.

Here is my table in my index.html.erb file :

```
<table id='dttb' role='datatable' class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-source="<%= datatable_users_path(format: :json) %>">
</table>
```

Here is my form in the index aswell :

```
<%= form_tag(datatable_users_path, method: :get) do %>
<%= submit_tag 'Apply filters' %>
```

My controller is rendering json like this :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => 'application' } # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
  format.json { render json: UserDatatable.new(params) }
end
```

and my user_datatable.rb gets its raw_record with this :

```
def get_raw_records
@users = User.all
if(@id.present?)
  @users = @users.id(@id)
end

return @users
end
```

The problem is this @id in the last file. This should be the params[:id] that my form is giving to the controller, and i want to use it in a scope to filter the User.all with it, so that the table displays only the entries that passed the scope.

I don't understand how to pass the data that my form gets to the user_datatable.rb

On the gem [github](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails#pass-options-to-the-datatable-class) there is a way to do it but it doesn't seem to work with the form data that i'm getting in the controller.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Did you solve this?